# React Native Concat String To Json Object

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I want to access Json data by append string as key of data.
Code Below :

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username:'',
        password:'',
        data:null
    } 
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5df5c95e0bbce135bb51e276")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((res)=> {    
      this.setState({data:res})
    })
  }
  signin_btn=()=>{

    var usernameInput = this.state.username;
    console.warn(usernameInput);
    console.warn(this.state.data.users.concat({usernameInput}));
  }
```

For Example:
if username is "ABC"
Then I want

```
this.state.data.users.ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting dynamic key in an object is easy. Use `[]` operator to set a dynamic key in an object.

```
let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
let dynamicKey = 'newKey'
obj[dynamicKey] = 3;

console.log(obj) // {a: 1, b: 2, dynamicKey: 3}
```